# Wordpress | マルチサイト運用

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

現在テストサーバ内に、１サイトに日本語版,英語版があり、それぞれのWordpressで運用しておりこれをマルチサイト運用へ設定変更したいです。

同一サーバ内で別ドメインで運用しているんですが、設定しようとしたら 
:20080ポートでは使用できません
Wordpressのツール→ネットワーク設置をクリックした画面内で表示されます。Apacheのエラーではありません。

とエラーがでてしまいました。 
（セキュリティポリシーの都合で:20080ポートでそれぞれ運用しています。）

また、現在それぞれ別ドメインで動いており、 
日本語：http://examplejp.com:20080 
英語：http://exampleen.com:20080 
のように動いています。

調べたのですが、Wordpressでは設定不可能でしょうか？ 
ポートの設定変更については社内の管理者に了承が必要で、できれば何かポート変更ではない解決策を取りたいです。